# Zelle POST API gateway timeout issue

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, zelle

We are implementing the zelle api for creating a new recipient and we are getting a gateway timeout issue.
All the Get api calls are working fine, but POST and PUT calls are getting timed out.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v5ZA.png)

Tried with different credentials too, but doesn't work

Comment: Engineering has deployed a patch for Zelle (based on a different question here on Stack Overflow). Please try again. If you encounter issues, please include the date/time and `x-request-id` from the response header if possible.